# Setting the Sender name in outgoing email

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

I am trying to change the Sender Name in an email that i am sending using apex. I would appreciate it if some one can help me understand how salesforce sets the sender's name in an email.

Here is my code.

```
public static Messaging.SendEmailResult[] SendEmail(Set<string> toAddresses, string subject, string body, Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] attachments){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Admin');
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setToAddresses(new List<string>(toAddresses));
        email.setPlainTextBody(body);
        email.setFileAttachments(attachments);
        return Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    }
```

Pretty straight forward, i would assume my Sender's name would be "Salesforce Admin". However when that did not work, i did some googling and found that the name could be coming from my Email settings.

Here is a screenshot of my email settings.

[image]

Here are my results and i am very confused.

The Sender's name says 'Rohita N Jakkana" when the to email is an Email in my org and it says "Salesforce Admin" when the to email is a gmail.

Thanks in advance.